# Rebuild Sitecore Search index and link database in a background process

Tags: sitecore, staging

We have a staged environment with 1 CMS and 3 Slave servers

I want to create a page on the slave server, which will be called by the staging module on a successful publish, that will rebuild all indexes and the links database.

I know I can use:

```cs
Globals.LinkDatabase.Rebuild(Factory.GetDatabase("web"));
```

to rebuild the link database.

How do I get the above code in a separate process that has access to the sitecore context and also how do I rebuild all the indexes for the web database - again in a separate background thread.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've come across this issue before with Sitecore and took a slightly different approch.  Instead of having a page that the staging module calls I tapped into the publish:end event and added a custom handler to rebuild the Link Database.

```xml
<event name="publish:end">
    <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer, Sitecore.Kernel" method="ClearCache">
        <sites hint="list">
            <site>website</site>
        </sites>
    </handler>
    <handler type="Sitecore.EventHandlers.CredentialCacheClearer, Sitecore.EventHandlers" method="ClearCache">
        <sites hint="list">
            <site>website</site>
        </sites>
    </handler>

    // Custom Publish Action Below
    <handler type="Customized.Publish.LinkDatabase, Customized" method="Process"/>
</event>
```

```cs
namespace Customized.Publish
{
    public class LinkDatabase
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Rebuild the web link database.
        /// </summary>

        public void Process()
        {
            // Web db
            Sitecore.Globals.LinkDatabase.Rebuild(Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("web"));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// For invoking as an event, typically publish:end.
        /// </summary>
        public void Process(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            this.Process();
        }
    }
}
```